# how to make pytorch lstm model for two input parameters

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I have a project where the future number of passengers is predicted using lstm. [full program link](https://github.com/tyt34/forecasting-pytorch-passengeres/blob/master/main_2.ipynb).
As input data, the passenger traffic for the previous time of this kind:

```
cd = [112, 118, 132, 129, 121, 135, ...]
```

The model on putorch for training has the following code:

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self, 
        num_classes, 
        input_size, 
        hidden_size, 
        num_layers
    ):
        super(LSTM, self).__init__()
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.seq_length = seq_length
        
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(
          input_size=input_size, 
          hidden_size=hidden_size,
          num_layers=num_layers, 
          batch_first=True
        )
        
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        h_0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size))
        c_0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size))
        ula, (h_out, _) = self.lstm(x, (h_0, c_0))
        h_out = h_out.view(-1, self.hidden_size)
        out = self.fc(h_out)
        return out
```

This model works and I have a question, what needs to be configured in this model so that it can take two parameters as input? for example, an additional array where the number of days off per month is counted?

```
an = [11, 9, 8, 9, 9, 8, ...]
```

In the file (in rep on github) "main_3" and "chat_model" I tried to do some operations, but nothing happened.

Comment: Do you need to change anything? Given that `input_size` is a constructor parameter, can't you just appropriately set this parameter when creating the model object?

Comment: the problem is that I don't know what needs to be adjusted so that it takes two parameters. I tried to change both the model and the input data during training but did not achieve a positive result.

Comment: Where do you create the model object? i.e. lstm_model = LSTM(...) Can't you just change the input_size parameter here? And then add the extra dimension to your data

Comment: I create lstm_model = LSTM(...)  in file which in rep.